# Can I reuse It.Any argument descriptors in Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have some code similar to

```
FooMock.Setup( m => m.Bar( It.Is<BarArg>( x => long_test_x_is_ok(x) ) );
```

naively, I thought I could rewrite this as:

```
var barArg = It.Is<BarArg>( x => long_test_x_is_ok(x) );
FooMock.Setup( m => m.Bar( barArg ) );
```

but Moq doesn't love me.  Is there a may to do this?

Similarly, some of our class names are quite long.  I'd like to refactor the calls to

```
It.IsAny<AnnoyinglyLongClassNameHere>()
```

into something shorter

```
var anyAlcnh = It.IsAny<AnnoyinglyLongClassNameHere>;
```

doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it does not work is `Setup` is actually taking in a [`Expression<Action<IFoo>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions(v=vs.110).aspx) not just a `Action<IFoo>`.

It never actually calls the `Action` you passed in, what it does is it takes the expression, pulls it apart and parses each component piece. Because of that you can't pull out `barArg` because that would make `barArg` a "black box" to the expression parser and would not know what the variable represents.

The best you could do is

```
//Assuming Bar has the signature "void Bar(BarArg barArg)". 
//If it was "Baz Bar(BarArg barArg)" use "Expression<Func<IFoo, Baz>>" instead.
Expression<Action<IFoo>> setup =  m => m.Bar(It.Is<BarArg>(x => long_test_x_is_ok(x)));
FooMock.Setup(setup);
```

The IsAny has the same problem, however for that you could make an alias to shorten the class name.

```
//At the top of your file with your other using statements
using ShortName = Some.Namespace.AnnoyinglyLongClassNameHere;

//Down in your unit test
FooMock.Setup(m => m.Bar(It.IsAny<ShortName>());
```

Comment: The answer is fundamentally correct. However it is not true that `var` defaults to a delegate type `D` (as opposed to the expression tree `Expression<D>`). You simply cannot assign a lambda arrow directly to an implicitly typed local variable. Also, we do not know the return type of the `Bar` method. You seem to assume it returns the same type as the type of its argument? It could return `void` (the asker seems to not call `.Returns`).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Both of those mistakes where from writing code in browsers without being able to check my work. I have corrected the mistakes in the answer, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: I think you should assume that `FooMock` is an instance of `Moq.Mock<IFoo>`. Then it will be `Expression<Action<IFoo>>` resp. `Expression<Func<IFoo, Baz>>`.

Comment: It seems so obvious now that you say it. Thanks again